# Proportion in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, subquery, window-functions

My table is like this

```
C1   Bool    Count

A    TRUE     5
A    FALSE    5
B    FALSE    6
C    TRUE     2
C    FALSE    8
```

I want to calculate the portion of count for each type of Bool, group by C1. The ideal result should be

```
C1   Bool    Portion

A    TRUE     0.5
A    FALSE    0.5
B    FALSE    1
C    TRUE     0.2
C    FALSE    0.8
```

I am not really sure how to achieve this. Really appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty similar to your previous question, but without aggregation.

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use window functions:

```
select t.*, count / sum(count) over(partition by c1) ratio
from mytable t
```

In earlier versions, an alternative is a join or correlated subquery:

```
select t.*, count / (select sum(t1.count) from mytable t1 where t1.c1 = t.c1) ratio
from mytable t
```

Comment: Maybe you should multiply by 1.0 to get a floating point result. Wait... I think MySQL uses floating point by default.

Comment: @TheImpaler: indeed, MySQL does not do integer division, so this works as such.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a subquery to get the SUM

Also you can round the results .

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `C1` VARCHAR(1),
>   `Bool` VARCHAR(5),
>   `Count` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`C1`, `Bool`, `Count`)
> VALUES
>   ('A', 'TRUE', '5'),
>   ('A', 'FALSE', '5'),
>   ('B', 'FALSE', '6'),
>   ('C', 'TRUE', '2'),
>   ('C', 'FALSE', '8');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT `C1`, `Bool`,  `Count` / (SELECT SUM(`Count`) sumcount FROM table1 WHERE `C1` = t1.`C1`) perc
> FROM table1 t1
> ```
>
> ```
> C1 | Bool  |   perc
> :- | :---- | -----:
> A  | TRUE  | 0.5000
> A  | FALSE | 0.5000
> B  | FALSE | 1.0000
> C  | TRUE  | 0.2000
> C  | FALSE | 0.8000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=aeab21516def9536a66d79e489efff47)*